# Hazelcast multiple left joins not working for two it is working fine

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I am new to Hazelcast Jet and I m tryin to join 4 datas but join is not working as accepted I am not sure what wrong I am doing as for two tables it is working fine. Please help
My Code:

```
BatchStageWithKey<Object, Object> jdbcGroupByKey = batch1.groupingKey(jdbcData ->  {
                 // logic for creating key   
             });

    BatchStageWithKey<Object, Object> jdbcGroupByKey2 = batch2.groupingKey(jdbcData ->  {
                 // logic for creating key   
             });

BatchStageWithKey<Object, Object> jdbcGroupByKey3 = batch3.groupingKey(jdbcData ->  {
                 // logic for creating key   
             });
```

Now  joining both with left join

```
BatchStage<Entry<Object, Tuple2<Object, List<Object>>>> d = jdbcGroupByKey.aggregate2(AggregateOperations.pickAny(),jdbcGroupByKey1,AggregateOperations.toList());
```

This works fine but when I try it with multiple it's not working:
Here I convert "d" to `BatchStage<Object>`

```
BatchStage<Entry<Object, Tuple2<Object, List<Object>>>> d2 = d1.aggregate2(AggregateOperations.pickAny(),jdbcGroupByKey1,AggregateOperations.toList());
```

This just example there can be 5 tables also so cannot use Tuple3 , so what can I do please help.

Comment: Hi all, I solved this issue, actually after first left join in second left join I have to consider it as many-to-many instead of one-to-many, so I have to use  AggregateOperations.toList() instead of AggregateOperations.pickAny()...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `aggregate3()`, or `aggregateBuilder()` if you have more than 3 inputs to aggregate. What you do in your example is you're aggregating the output of aggregation. You can do that too, but it's less efficient. It would look like this:

```java
BatchStage<Entry<Object, Tuple2<Object, List<Object>>>> d1 = 
    jdbcGroupByKey.aggregate2(pickAny(),jdbcGroupByKey1,toList());
BatchStage<Entry<Object, Tuple2<Tuple2<Object, List<Object>>, List<Object>>>> d2 = 
    d1.groupingKey(Entry::getKey)
      .aggregate2(pickAny(),jdbcGroupByKey1,toList());
```

(Code not compiled, there can be a mistake, but hope you get the idea.)

Comment: Thanks for the replay but this would be like static and in my case inputs will not be fix and also not joins, it can be left, right or inner, I have checked aggregateBuilder, but as I said inputs are not fix and Tuples5 is max so how can I use more than that? any reference or idea

Comment: I have followed this link: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet/blob/master/examples/co-group/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/jet/examples/cogroup/BatchCoGroup.java